# Mandrill sendTemplate not working in IE9 and Below

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, mandrill

We've managed to narrow down an issue in a project in IE9 and below to the following call:

```
m.messages.sendTemplate(params, function(res){
    afterValidation();
}, function(err) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

With m being the mandrill object.

afterValidation takes the user to the next page. However because of IE<=9, it blocks the sendTemplate and thus afterValidation call. I've tried taking the Mandrill Api wrapper and modifying it so it reads this:

```
try  {
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari, Chrome
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e) {
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

so that it returns an XMLHTTPRequest for an normal browser and tries to make a different object type for IE however this doesn't work either and I'm completely stumped for other options. Is there a specific request I can return that Mandrill and IE can use so that the user can proceed to the next page and receive their email through Mandrill?